# How to make the box-shadow animation to bounce off the sides? Where am I wrong?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a division (`.Animate`) whose `box-shadow` property is being animated. I want it to bounce off the right side, like the one I've applied to the second division (`.Animate2`). Please run the code snippet to see the animation. Required animation is showcased by the second division.

For the second division I've made the required animation with `:before` element by animating its width & left margin. But I would like a way of eliminating the psuedo element. I have the code where I'm trying to replicate the animation keyframes of `WidthAni` into the keyframes of `BoxShadowAni`, but the animation of both divisions aren't the same. What am I missing? Where does my logic fail me? (Comments after the keyframes explain my logic.)

Here's my code:

```css
body {
  background: #222;
  color: #ddd;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 3em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Animate {
  box-shadow: 600px 0px #ddd inset;
  color: #222;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  animation: BoxShadowAni 5.0s infinite linear;
}

.Animate2 {
  color: #222;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  position: relative;
}

.Animate2:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #ddd;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: WidthAni 5.0s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes BoxShadowAni {
  0% {box-shadow: 0px 0px #ddd inset;}/*Starts from left edge*/
  10% {box-shadow: 600px 0px #ddd inset;}/*To grow upto the left edge*/
  20% {box-shadow: -5px 0px #ddd inset;}/*To reduce in length upto the right edge*/
  25% {box-shadow: -5px 0px #ddd inset;}/*To stay for a while and then bounce back*/
  35% {box-shadow: -600px 0px #ddd inset;}/*Grow upto the right edge*/
  45% {box-shadow: 0px 0px #ddd inset;}/*To reduce in length upto the left edge*/
  100% {box-shadow: 0px 0px #ddd inset;}/*To insert a pause b4 animation loops back*/
}

@-webkit-keyframes WidthAni {
  0% {width: 0px}
  10% {width: 100%;left: 0;right: 0}
  20% {width: 5%;left: 95%;}
  25% {width: 5%;left: 95%;}
  35% {width: 100%;left: 0%;}
  45% {width: 0%;}
  100% {width: 0%;}
}
```

```html
<div class='Animate'>BoxShadow</div>
<div class='Animate2'>Width Ani</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean "bounce off the side"? Do you have a picture or something?

Comment: The required animation is portrayed by the second division where I've used :before element instead of box-shadow. I want to apply the same animation to the first div using box-shadow property.

Comment: Got it sorry. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I think the biggest problem is trying to control `box-shadow` the way you want to. Especially when its `inset` some odd things happen. (your example blinks and flickers). See below for alternative solutions that give the same result without using box-shadow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is when you are changing the shadow to another. I suggest you to rely on multiple box shadow to achieve this and you will have a better rendring. The trick it to be sure that you always cover the whole area when changing the shadow.

So instead of going from `300px 0px #ddd inset` to `-300px 0px #ddd inset` where you will have the flicker you can do this:

`300px 0px #ddd inset,0px 0px #ddd inset` to `300px 0px #ddd inset,-300px 0px #ddd inset` then to `0px 0px #ddd inset,-300px 0px #ddd inset`

```css
body {
  background: #222;
  color: #ddd;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 3em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Animate {
  color: #222;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  animation: BoxShadowAni 5.0s infinite linear;
}

.Animate2 {
  color: #222;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  position: relative;
}

.Animate2:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #ddd;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: WidthAni 5.0s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes BoxShadowAni {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px #ddd inset, 0px 0px #ddd inset;
  }
  10% {
    box-shadow: 300px 0px #ddd inset,0px 0px #ddd inset;
  }
  10.1% {
    box-shadow: 300px 0px #ddd inset,-300px 0px #ddd inset;
  }
  10.2% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px #ddd inset,-300px 0px #ddd inset;
  }
  20% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px #ddd inset,-5px 0px #ddd inset;
  }
  25% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px #ddd inset,-5px 0px #ddd inset;
  }
  35% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px #ddd inset,-300px 0px #ddd inset;
  }
  35.1% {
    box-shadow: 300px 0px #ddd inset,-300px 0px #ddd inset;
  }
  35.2% {
    box-shadow: 300px 0px #ddd inset,0px 0px #ddd inset;
  }
  45%,100% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px #ddd inset,0px 0px #ddd inset;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes WidthAni {
  0% {
    width: 0px
  }
  10% {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0
  }
  20% {
    width: 5%;
    left: 95%;
  }
  25% {
    width: 5%;
    left: 95%;
  }
  35% {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0%;
  }
  45% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='Animate'>BoxShadow</div>
<div class='Animate2'>Width Ani</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so using a `box-shadow` seems like a really complex way to do this and its hard to manipulate.

If you're going to use a pseudo-class just make one with a background color and move it. *Example #1*.

If you don't want a pseudo-class animating a background is probably easier so you can do that with a gradient *Example #2* but that can sometimes have a blurry edge. So another option is to use an image (base64 encoded and inlined to avoid any additional files) *Example #3*.

Finally, the above solutions require that you use the same color text as the background. BUT there's a CSS property that's made for this: `clip-path`. As a bonus it works on inline elements too... *Examples 4 & 5*

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
}

.reveal {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: #333;
}

.pseudo {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.pseudo:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ddd;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-animation: pseudo 10s infinite ease-in-out;
          animation: pseudo 10s infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pseudo {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatex(-100%);
            transform: translatex(-100%);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatex(100%);
            transform: translatex(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatex(-100%);
            transform: translatex(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes pseudo {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translatex(-100%);
            transform: translatex(-100%);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translatex(100%);
            transform: translatex(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translatex(-100%);
            transform: translatex(-100%);
  }
}
.background {
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAC1JREFUOBFjvHv37n8GKgImKpoFNmrUQMpDdDQMR8OQjBAYTTZkBBqalhEYhgAuSwO+G+SAowAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: left top;
  -webkit-animation: background 5s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
          animation: background 5s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes background {
  0% {
    background-size: 0% 100%;
  }
  50% {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: left top;
  }
  51% {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: right top;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 0% 100%;
    background-position: right top;
  }
}

@keyframes background {
  0% {
    background-size: 0% 100%;
  }
  50% {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: left top;
  }
  51% {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-position: right top;
  }
  100% {
    background-size: 0% 100%;
    background-position: right top;
  }
}
.gradient {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #dddddd 0%, #dddddd 50%, rgba(221, 221, 221, 0) 50.01%, rgba(221, 221, 221, 0) 100%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  -webkit-animation: gradient 5s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
          animation: gradient 5s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 100% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -100% 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 100% 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -100% 0%;
  }
}
.clip {
  color: #4394ED;
  background: #ddd;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
          clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  -webkit-animation: clip 5s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
          animation: clip 5s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes clip {
  0% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 0 100%);
            clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
            clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%);
            clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%);
  }
}

@keyframes clip {
  0% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 0 100%);
            clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 0, 0 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
            clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%);
            clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 100% 100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Text Reveal</h2>

<div class="reveal pseudo">Reveal Text (Pseudo Class)</div>

<div class="reveal gradient">Reveal Text (gradient)</div>

<div class="reveal background">Reveal Text (background-image)</div>

<div class="reveal clip">Reveal Text (clip-path)</div>

<span class="clip">Works on inline elements too...</span>
```

Comment: since you are only changing the width size of the background, you can omit the `top` keyword and use only left/right

Comment: @Temani Afif      Awesome alternatives by Bryce Howitson; But can't this be done with box-shadows? Using box-shadow was the limitation that I imposed on myself as a challenge to tackle. I'm sure it can't be impossible, just some more well thought out keyframes should do the trick... What do you guys think?

Comment: I think it is doable. But it seems to have performance issues. Not sure about you but I get lots of flicker and jankiness with the box-shadow example. I think its because the properties don't seem to be animating but being replaced. Perhaps another way to do it would be add multiple box shadows in a row so they stack and fake the animation? I've never tried animating a property like that.

Comment: @YourPalNurav have you considered the `alternate` keyword in your animation? That might decrease the keyframes you need.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes that's true but I always try to provide examples that are readable by everyone. Just because you don't need the keywords doesn't mean anyone who looks at it will understand what's going on.